# Save history of incremental changes of the flow without cloning them in Mosaic Decisions

Tags: mosaic-decisions

While configuring a particular data pipeline in **Mosaic Decisions**, I want to try out different operations by using the available **process nodes**. I would like to keep the first few configured nodes for future reference and continue to add some other nodes.

To do this, I'm currently **cloning** the flow after each incremental change. But, due to this, many flows are getting configured and it becomes very difficult to keep track.

Is there any alternative way to save the **history** of these **multiple configurations** of the flow for future reference without cloning and executing them separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the history of changes you have made in the flow by simply saving it as a version using **Save As Version** option provided in the **canvas header**.

[image: Save As Version option]

You can also add a **description** for each of the incremental steps and edit a particular **version** later if you want. Later, you can also **execute** each of the **saved versions** separately by **publishing** that version from the **Version tab** and then
executing it normally.

[image: Version Tab]

Comment: I have saved multiple versions of the flow. Do all the versions get imported on migration ? and what is the way to migrate a particular version.

Comment: @aj1198 Only the published version of the flow would get imported. You can also change the published version of the flow from the Versions tab.